# When server boots i get the error "blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 "

Tags: filesystems, system-failure

I rebooted a server due to it not responding, it shows the following entries on screen during reboot :

```
[ 30.5681041 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 31.6680301 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 31.7280471 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0,sector 0
[ 32.7920341 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0,sector 0
[ 32.8520121 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd8, sector 0
32.9400141 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd8, sector 0
33.0000421 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
[
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda1:
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-19+deb9u2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
(initramfs) [ 30.5681041 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 31.6680301 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 31.7280471 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0,sector 0
[ 32.7920341 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0,sector 0
[ 32.8520121 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd8, sector 0
32.9400141 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd8, sector 0
33.0000421 blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
[
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda1:
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-19+deb9u2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
(initramfs)
```

I couldn't figure out how to get it back online so I restored a backup from 31/12/22 and it started up but did show the messages below. What was the problem? Is this issue now resolved or does it need further work? Any advice/information is helpful.

```
    [    0.923808] scsi host0: ioc0: LSI53C1030 B0, FwRev=01032920h, Ports=1, MaxQ=128, IRQ=17
    [    0.990217] e1000 0000:02:00.0 eth0: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:50:56:a9:6b:c3
    [    0.990223] e1000 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
    [    0.990500] e1000 0000:02:00.0 ens32: renamed from eth0
    [    1.092004] ata_piix 0000:00:07.1: version 2.13
    [    1.092640] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     VMware   Virtual disk     1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
    [    1.092647] scsi target0:0:0: Beginning Domain Validation
    [    1.092974] scsi target0:0:0: Domain Validation skipping write tests
    [    1.092975] scsi target0:0:0: Ending Domain Validation
    [    1.092993] scsi target0:0:0: FAST-40 WIDE SCSI 80.0 MB/s ST (25 ns, offset 127)
    [    1.093038] scsi host1: ata_piix
    [    1.093467] scsi host2: ata_piix
    [    1.093506] ata1: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0x1060 irq 14
    [    1.093508] ata2: PATA max UDMA/33 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0x1068 irq 15
    [    1.263417] ata2.00: ATAPI: VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive, 00000001, max UDMA/33
    [    1.267945] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/33
    [    1.268354] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
    [    1.270753] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 524288000 512-byte logical blocks: (268 GB/250 GiB)
    [    1.270772] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
    [    1.270774] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 61 00 00 00
    [    1.270794] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable
    [    1.270795] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [    1.275928]  sda: sda1 sda2
    [    1.276171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
    [    1.284239] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 1x/1x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
    [    1.284242] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
    [    1.284487] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
    [    1.344797] random: fast init done
    [    1.431893] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    1.431939] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    1.495888] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    1.495934] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    2.567878] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    2.567955] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    2.627864] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    2.627925] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    3.691873] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    3.691935] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    3.751875] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    3.751938] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    4.831911] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    4.832013] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    4.891922] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    4.892063] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    5.955882] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    5.955952] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    6.015860] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    6.015921] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    7.095940] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    7.096093] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    7.155972] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    7.156184] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    8.223946] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    8.224102] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    8.283973] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    8.284184] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    9.375904] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    9.376020] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [    9.435956] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [    9.436115] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   10.499906] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   10.500019] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   10.559900] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   10.559997] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   11.643921] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   11.644052] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   11.703916] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   11.704065] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   11.704179] random: crng init done
    [   14.517301] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   14.517429] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   14.677342] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   14.677471] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   16.459906] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   16.460130] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   16.519918] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   16.520094] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   17.611873] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   17.612021] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   17.671874] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   17.671996] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   18.735911] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   18.736027] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   18.795916] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   18.796031] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   19.887923] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   19.888059] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   19.947864] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   19.947975] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   21.011876] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   21.011977] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   21.071875] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   21.071986] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   22.163888] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   22.163990] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   22.223898] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   22.224013] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   23.287876] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   23.288018] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   23.347895] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   23.347996] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   24.439884] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   24.439986] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   24.499888] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   24.499987] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   25.563896] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   25.564019] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   25.623894] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   25.623995] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   26.715901] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   26.716001] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   26.775882] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   26.775983] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   27.839890] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   27.839992] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   27.899887] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   27.899988] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   28.991872] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   28.991975] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   29.051892] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   29.052000] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   30.143903] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   30.144005] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   30.203898] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   30.204000] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   31.267897] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   31.268000] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   31.327901] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   31.328002] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   32.419878] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   32.419981] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   32.479889] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   32.479990] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   32.539922] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   32.540067] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
    [   32.599893] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [   32.599995] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
```

I'm running a vmware virtual machine and the operating system is Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your initramfs to load the `floppy` kernel module, but I guess your VM does not actually have a virtual floppy drive?

To disable the `floppy` module, run the following commands:

```
sudo rmmod floppy
echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```